# Error loading existing shared library (.so) on Android app (unsatisfiedlinkerror native method not found)

Tags: java, android, c, linux, android-ndk

This is my scenario:

-) I have a shared library called libpsp.so generated by ndk-build. This lib was generated using around 30 .c files.

Android.mk used:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := psp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := (My .c files)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

-) ndk-build automatically put the libpsp.so in the dir /libs/armeabi

-) On my Java code I have:

```
    private native int calculateCoefficient(double w, double v_st_e_prev, double c_l);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    **//Loads successfully
    System.loadLibrary("psp");**

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    TextView lv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    **//Returns an error: unsatisfiedlinkerror native method not found
    lv.setText(Integer.toString(calculateCoefficient(1,1,1)));**
}
```

-) One of the .c files used to build the shared library has the calculateCoefficient method with the signature:

```
sint32_t calculateCoefficient(double_t w, double_t v_st_e_prev, double_t *c_l);
```

So if the calculateCoefficient method is present in the .so library, why can't Android find it? I just started working with NDK so sorry if I missed something to obvious, but I've done some research and I can't find the answer to this.

UPDATE1: I don't have access to the actual code, the library was generated by someone else, all I have are the .h files with the methods signatures. So I can't edit the .c files used to create the library.

Comment: First, use the ndk objdump with the -d flag to disassemble your .so and grep it for the function name to find out what is actually there.  Next, use the implicitly rooted emulator's adb shell, or else the run-as tool with a debug build on a device, in order to examine the install and see what actually got unpacked.

Answer (score 1):

Your signature is wrong.  It needs to be JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_classname_methodname(JNIENV* env, jobject obj, ...)  where ... are the parameters you actually want to pass.  pointers cannot be passed, if you want an array you'd use a jdoublearray, if you want to just pass a double by reference you'd need to pass down a class that holds a double and set that field on the object.

Comment: The signature was obtained from the header file which I have access, but I can't change the C code neither the method signature.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was partially incorrect.  The missing Java_classname_etc prepend will indeed explain the problem.  If you can't fix the current library, then write a new library with properly named jni compatible functions which wraps and invokes the existing library.  Load the existing library first and then the wrapper.

Comment: So, I would have to create a .c file with a JNI function for every function that I want to call?

Comment: Yes.  The exact method name and signature needs to match.  That's how Java knows what to call.  But its not uncommon to write a wrapper layer to interface between an existing C library and Java.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how would the JNI function be considering I want to call the calculateCoefficient function described on the question?

Comment: Create a Java method marked as native method and then let the JNI header generator "javah" generate the correct .h files from the Java file. You should read more about JNI and how it works.